Inequality regarding dimension of intersection of arbitary subspaces of a vector space

Suppose $U_1,U_2,\ldots,U_k$ are subspaces for an n dimensional vectorspace $V$ , show that $\dim(U_1 \cap\cdots\cap U_k) ≥
\sum_{i=1}^k
\dim U_i −(k −1)n$

I saw a proof of this question involving induction but I am don't quite get why this statement should be intuitively true. The only observation I made in the inductions step is that, the proof relies on subspace being smaller dimension than vector space and the equality relating sum of vector subspaces with entire space and intersection of said subspaces.
But, I am trying to find if there is some potential geometric intuition for this identity to be a true/heuristics to understand this inequality.

Should the problem start with "Suppose $U_1,U_2,\ldots,U_k$"? That is, $k$ subspaces, not $n$, as $n$ is the dimension of $V$, and you only every use $k$ subspaces.
